# InflateException caused by OutOfMemoryError during layout inflation

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I am trying to implement google's SlidingTabLayout for tabs. Tabs will be displayed in the lower half of the screen while the upper half contains normal text and image views.I know there is something wrong in the views implementation but I cant figure out exactly.

For java.lang.OutOfMemoryError I tried setting RAM value equal to HAXM value and increased the VM Heap to 256MB but it still gives the same error.

Error:

```
    08-24 15:56:32.048    2032-2032/com.company.company.testapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com..company.company.testapp, PID: 2032
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com..company.company.testapp/com..company.company.testapp.ViewProfile}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.aldoshik.rewardtrunk.rewardtrunk5.ViewProfile.onCreate(ViewProfile.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.company.company.testapp.ViewProfile.onCreate(ViewProfile.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1638998616 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 246MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.company.company.testapp.ViewProfile.onCreate(ViewProfile.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

XML Layout:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.company.company.testapp.ViewProfile"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_page_background_blur">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_profile"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_profile"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/profile_above"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp">

            <ImageView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/profilepic"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="Main Image"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="1dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="   Edit Profile   "
            android:id="@+id/go_to_editprofile_btn"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"/>

</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile_above"
            android:background="#f7f7f7"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.aldoshik.rewardtrunk.rewardtrunk5.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="2dp"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.aldoshik.rewardtrunk.rewardtrunk5.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

ViewProfile.java :

```
package com.company.company.testapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ViewProfile extends ActionBarActivity implements  ActionBar.TabListener {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    Context ctx = this;
    ViewPager mPager;
    SlidingTabLayout mTabs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_profile);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar_profile);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(new ProfilePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);

        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer,(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),toolbar);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view_profile, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }


    public class ProfilePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        String tabs[];
        public ProfilePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            ProfileFragment profileFragment = ProfileFragment.getInstance(position);
            return profileFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
             return tabs[position];
        }
    }

    public static class ProfileFragment extends Fragment{
        public TextView textView;
        public static ProfileFragment getInstance(int position){
            ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("Position", position);
            profileFragment.setArguments(args);
            return profileFragment;

        }

        public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){

            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_self, container, false);
            textView = (TextView)  layout.findViewById (R.id.position);
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if(bundle!=null){
                textView.setText(bundle.getInt("position"));
            }
            return layout;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the background you're setting in your `RelativeLayout`

> android:background="@drawable/profile_page_background_blur"

The bitmap's size is too large for the main thread to handle, you should downscale the bitmap and set the background.

[`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) can be used to do this:

```
public class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

    private TaskCallback callback;
    private Activity activity;

    public ImageLoadTask(Activity activity) {
        this.callback = activity;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        int width;
        int height;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) {
            display.getSize(size);
            width = size.x;
            height = size.y;
        } else {
            width = display.getWidth();
            height = display.getHeight();
        }
        return scaledDownBitmap(params[0], width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        callback.onImageLoaded(bitmap);
    }

    public interface TaskCallback {
        void onImageLoaded(Bitmap bitmap);
    }

    public Bitmap scaledDownBitmap(int resource, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResource(), resource, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        return resizedBitmap;
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

Have your activity `implement` the `ImageLoadTask.TaskCallback` and set your `RelativeLayout`'s background there.

To use the `AsyncTask` do the following:

```
ImageLoadTask task = new ImageLoadTask(this);
task.execute(R.drawable.profile_page_background_blur)
```

and on the task's callback do the following:

```
@Override
public void onImageLoaded(Bitmap bitmap) {
    view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResouce(), bitmap));
}
```

I hope this helps.

Always remember to offload bitmap work into a separate thread, checkout [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html). You should also consider using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or any other 3rd party library. They simplify your work :)

Comment: It's not too large for the main thread to handle -- it's too large for the whole *heap* to handle. I know of no Android device with a maximum heap size large enough to allow a 1.5 GB allocation.

Loading the image in another thread will not help.

Comment: @SnildDolkow oh, I didn't notice the resource's size !! That's a little too much don't you think ?

Comment: Yes, that is *way* too much. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the interesting part of your stack trace:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1638998616 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 246MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
        ...
```

It tries to allocate a 1638998616-byte bitmap. That's over 1.5 GB! That is a *very* large bitmap.

The stack trace tells us that the image is being loaded during initialization of a RelativeLayout -- probably as a background. The image is being loaded from one of your drawable resources.

Check the background attribute of your layout file's RelativeLayout tags, and check the size of the corresponding drawable resource.

Remember that an unpacked image in memory will be the *uncompressed* size (slightly oversimplified, it will require W * H * 4 bytes of memory).